# Will the 3.16.0-4-amd64 image break my system, due to BUILD_EXCLUSIVE failing?

Tags: debian, apt

I'm running Debian 9 on a Dell Latitude E7250. This is a 64-bit i5 CPU.

This morning I just ran `apt-get dist-upgrade`. It proceeded to update my image via linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64_3.16.43-2+deb8u5_amd64 package. In the process, I received the following error:

```
Error!  The dkms.conf for this module includes a BUILD_EXCLUSIVE directive which
does not match this kernel/arch.  This indicates that it should not be built.
```

The update then continued and finished without prompting for my input. Is my system going to poop on itself when I reboot? If so, what should I do?

Entire output below:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  virtualbox-5.1
The following packages will be upgraded:
  heroku linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 48.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 2,048 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Get:1 https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt ./ heroku 6.14.25-1 [14.6 MB]
Get:2 http://security-cdn.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64 amd64 3.16.43-2+deb8u5 [34.0 MB]
Fetched 48.5 MB in 1s (48.3 MB/s)                                                    
Reading changelogs... Done
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 309446 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64_3.16.43-2+deb8u5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64 (3.16.43-2+deb8u5) over (3.16.43-2+deb8u3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../heroku_6.14.25-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking heroku (6.14.25-1) over (6.14.24-1) ...
Setting up heroku (6.14.25-1) ...
Setting up linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64 (3.16.43-2+deb8u5) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
Error!  The dkms.conf for this module includes a BUILD_EXCLUSIVE directive which
does not match this kernel/arch.  This indicates that it should not be built.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-4-amd64
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found background image: /usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-grub.png
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-3-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.9.0-3-amd64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-4-amd64
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debian 9 uses the `4.9.0-3-amd64` version of the kernel, so I do not think you will get problems when you reboot. However, if you do.

1. Remove the old kernels from `/boot/`
2. `update-initramfs -c -v`

Now you will boot into Debian 9 with the kernel version of `4.9.0-3-amd64`.